# Xcode Debugger - how to single step at level of CPU instructions

Tags: xcode, debugging

This is definitely obsessive, but I am fascinated  by how cleverly the compiler translates C code into machine instructions.  Since I am a little fuzzy on some instructions, it would be helpful if I could watch the operation of a compiled program at the level of individual machine instructions - "below" the level of a C statement (which might generate several CPU instructions).  In other words, can I watch the registers/memory change after a single machine instruction?

I'm sure it's possible with some other debuggers, but I am only using Xcode.

Comment: gdb certainly can do it, and Xcode debugger is a gdb frontend, so the question is if it has any UI to call that gdb command.

Comment: Thanks, and the answer is 'yes' - Step Into w/Option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`si` is "Step Instruction", and `ni` is "Next Instruction".  They have the same semantics as "step" and "next" do for lines of code, just on the instruction level.

Comment: That sounds like gdb - can I do that from XCode?

Comment: shift-cmd-R brings up the console window, where (once you break) you get a standard GDB prompt.  Also, it looks like the Run menu has a "Step Into Instruction" item (opt-shift-cmd-I) and a "Step Over Instruction" item (opt-shift-cmd-O).

Comment: that's a capital "I" (as in "Indigo"), not a lower-case "L".

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to use Xcode's step over, step in, and step out commands with the debugger. The trick is to hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> *(Control)* key while you mouse over the debugger step icons to change the context. Underneath each step icon, the line will change to a dot and you can then step at the instruction level.

See the attached screenshot highlighted with a red oval.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

In the Debugger window, enable assembly: Run/Debugger display/Source and disassembly. Wait till you hit a breakpoint. Then use Run/Step into(over) instruction to step in assembly.

Comment: Thanks - I had the 'Step Into', but overlooked the OPTION key for machine level steps

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, didn't check closely enough - Step Into w/Option (Cmd-Opt-Shft-I = ⌘⌥⇧I)