# The first method in detail view controller is being skipped

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller

Is there something important I need in RoomItem to ensure that this method isn't skipped?  It's the very first one in my detail view controller, and it is continually skipped when I'm in debugging mode.  I'm sure I'm missing something ridiculously simple, but I've been staring at it for hours and just can't figure out what it is.

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end
@implementation DetailViewController
- (void)setDetailItem:(RoomItem *)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}
- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.
if (self.detailItem) {
    [_roomTxt setText:[_detailItem room]];
    [_buildingTxt setText:[_detailItem building]];
    [_dateTxt setText:[self dateCreatedString]];
    [_buildingImageView setImage:[_detailItem buildingImage]];
    _oi = [_detailItem objectIndex];
}
}
```

**MasterViewController (root table view) methods that alloc and init new and existing detailViewControllers**

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
//add button invokes this
DetailViewController *ivc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
NSLog(@"detailViewController allocated and initialized: %@", ivc);
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"detailViewController initialized: %@", self.detailViewController);
}
//navigates to detailViewController and passes it the item's data
self.detailViewController.detailItem = [[[RoomList sharedStore] getAllItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**Here is the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method that should be passing everything needed by the detail view controller, from the RoomList:sharedStore:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
}
//navigates to detailViewController and passes it the item's data
self.detailViewController.detailItem = [[[RoomList sharedStore] getAllItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**...and the RoomItem.m file:**

```
- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
[super awakeFromFetch];

UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageWithData:[self buildingThumbnailData]];
[self setPrimitiveValue:pic forKey:@"buildingThumbnail"];
}
- (id)initWithRoom:(NSString *)room Building:(NSString *)building 
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    [self setRoom:room];
    [self setBuilding:building];
}
return self;
}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class RoomItem;
//pic edit: added delegates
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate,
UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
{
__weak IBOutlet UITextField *roomField;
__weak IBOutlet UITextField *buildingField;
__weak IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;

UIPopoverController *imagePickerPopover;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) RoomItem *detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *updateBtn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *detailsBtn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *roomTxt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *buildingTxt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateTxt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *buildingImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *buildingImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSNumber *oi;
- (IBAction)backgroundTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)updateRoomItem:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goToReportDetails:(id)sender;
@end
```

**Edit:here is a pseudo-UML diagram that illustrates what I'm seeing when I step through with the debugger (it reads from left to right, top to bottom):**
[image]

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint *before* the if statement in your setter? I assume the setter is in your detail view controller `.m` file.

Comment: I did use a breakpoint at the if statement in the setter, and it never hit it.  It is at the very top of the DetailViewController.m file, but it skips immediately to the -(void)configureView method just below it.  I've added that to the initial post.

Comment: I have seen mutters lately about xcode failing to implement breakpoints in some cases, although nothing definite. Have you tried NSLog statements in your setter method? Is that the only code that calls configureView?

Comment: I've tried the NSLog within the setter, nothing doing...  There are several other methods that call configureView, but I've commented them all out now (with exception of those in the setDetailItem and viewDidLoad methods)...same results.  I also have it called inside of the @interface DetailViewController().  I've added this code to the first post.

Comment: The major problem this is causing is when I update the data model.  I believe that the setter being skipped is causing the objectIndex sorter to remain at nil, but the object.count for the data model is returning at least one.  Instead of updating the fetched model object, it just creates another.

Comment: How about adding code in tableView:... where you set the detailItem property to check that it has actually been written? NSLog the read value? And then maybe add a custom getter for the property with an NSLog to prove that the getter is being called? I know it sounds odd, but there is definitely something strange here.

Comment: Okay, did an NSLog/breakpoints in insertNewObject and tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath (both have been added above). Both logs return what is expected.  Something interesting happened with the breakpoint in insertNewObject. As I stepped through it, it jumped from [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES]; directly to the configureView method in the detailViewController.

Comment: The UINavigationController docs say "Pushing a view controller results in the display of the view it manages." So if the push eventually calls code (somehow) to configure the detailViewController, you might expect it to execute configureView sometime. But that doesn't explain why it's not being called in the setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, first things first. The reason -(void)setDetailItem:(RoomItem *)newDetailItem was being skipped is due to me not passing it the newly created RoomItem in the DVC.  I was doing this initially, but mistakenly got rid of it while trying to correct the issue somewhere else.

**In DetailViewController.m:**

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
RoomItem *newItem = [[RoomList sharedStore] createItem];

DetailViewController *ivc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

[ivc setDetailItem:newItem];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
NSLog(@"detailViewController allocated and initialized: %@", ivc);
}
```

Getting this to work though took some restructuring in the RoomList.m file. I had initially attempted to marry the create and update functions into one method. That doesn't fly if I'm creating in the MVC, and updating in the DVC.

**So I split the two up:**

```
- (RoomItem *)createItem
{
double order;

//create new roomItem
//tracks what number item it's creating
if ([allItems count] == 0) {
    order = 1.0;
}
else
{
    order = [[[allItems lastObject] objectIndex] doubleValue] + 1;
}
NSLog(@"Adding after %d items, order = %.2f", [allItems count], order);

RoomItem *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoomItem"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:context];

[p setObjectIndex:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:order]];
[p setDateCreated:[NSDate date]];
[allItems addObject:p];

[self saveChanges];

return p;
}
- (RoomItem *)updateItemWithRoom:(NSString *)room Building:(NSString *)building ObjectIndex:(NSNumber *)objectIndex DateCreated:(NSDate *)dateCreated ImageKey:(NSString *)imageKey BuildingImage:(UIImage *)buildingImage BuildingThumbnail:(UIImage *)buildingThumbnail BuildingThumbnailData:(NSData *)buildingThumbnailData
{
NSError *error = nil;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RoomItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

int32_t oid = [objectIndex integerValue] - 1;
NSLog(@"objectIndex = %d", oid);

RoomItem *currentRoomItem = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:oid];

//[currentRoomItem setItemEdited:YES];
[currentRoomItem setRoom:room];
[currentRoomItem setBuilding:building];
[currentRoomItem setImageKey:imageKey];
[currentRoomItem setBuildingImage:buildingImage];
[currentRoomItem setBuildingThumbnail:buildingThumbnail];
[currentRoomItem setBuildingThumbnailData:buildingThumbnailData];

[self saveChanges];

return currentRoomItem;
}
```

Lastly, the setDetailItem and configureView methods:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(RoomItem *)detailItem
{
if (_detailItem != detailItem) {
    _detailItem = detailItem;
    [self configureView];
}
}
- (void)configureView
{
if (self.detailItem) {
    [_roomTxt setText:[_detailItem room]];
    [_buildingTxt setText:[_detailItem building]];
    [_dateTxt setText:[self dateCreatedString]];
    [_buildingImageView setImage:[_detailItem buildingImage]];
}
}
```

This should serve as a lesson about taking the time to read the core data documentation, or any other for that matter...especially noobs like myself.

Thanks again to emrys57 for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange that the setter is not being called. I would take the line

```
self.detailViewController.detailItem = [[[RoomList sharedStore] getAllItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

and replace it with this code which might be a bit easier to follow:

```
RoomItem *tempItem = [[[RoomList sharedStore] getAllItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
DetailViewController *tempDVC = self.detailViewController; // could just use _detailViewController
tempDVC.detailItem = tempItem;  // breakpoint on this line
```

and then when the breakpoint hits, I would single step through the compiled assembler to find out where it goes. There are instructions for that at [Xcode Debugger - how to single step at level of CPU instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009009/xcode-debugger-how-to-single-step-at-level-of-cpu-instructions) - specifically the answer a couple of weeks ago from Max MacLeod.

I'd have written this as another comment since it's not really an answer, but it's too long!

Comment: I pasted your setter code into xcode and executed it much as you have here, on the iPad simulator... I'm afraid it executed perfectly. It did single step into the setter, which executed as one would expect.

Comment: The code you suggested is for tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath in MasterViewController.  The problem I'm having with the skipped setter is happening without ever leaving the detailView.  I wonder if this is an issue with initializing detailItem? If it didn't yet exist in the detailView, would it skip the setter that is looking for it to set it as new or skip the setter if it is not new?

Comment: Would it be worth while to create two, nearly identical DVC's? The first would only appear when there's a new detail item (insertNewObject), the second would appear when tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is evoked. Thank you for all your time and help by the way.

Comment: Ah, now, I can't see the code that you're suggesting is failing to call the setter. Have you not posted that, or am I lost again? And I definitely don't think adding more DVCs, when we don't understand the first one yet, is a good idea!

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just starting to feel like I should start from scratch. I've been banging my head against this wall for too long. Shouldn't the setter take care of initialization of detailItem? Or do I need to initialize it separately? It's odd that when this process gets to the updateItemWithRoom method, that it sees that the objectIndex of every detailItem/RoomItem is nil...and then it skips over saving most of the attributes to the data model. Most perplexing, indeed.

Comment: Now I'm getting even more confused than usual! The setDetailItem code will not be called when you do `[[DetailViewController alloc] init]`. It's only called when you write to the property, like `dvc.detailItem = ...`. Before then, the value of detailItem will be 0, unless you do something like `_detailItem = ...` in the `DetailViewController` init routine.

Comment: Like I said, it's a mess. I now have a hunch that I'm not creating new items properly in the item store. Initially, I tried marrying that function with an update function that was called by the UIButton updateButton in the DVC. It occurs to me now that this was probably a big no-no. I'll make some adjustments tomorrow morning, and post the results.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for helping me figure this out along the way emrys57! See my answer below.

Comment: No problem. It's only fair considering that you did help me reach a conclusion through clarifying what was actually happening.